# Program exits loop, can't understand why even with debugging

Tags: java, for-loop, pointers, data-structures

It fails at the example [0,0,1], the output is [0,1,0] instead of [1,0,0]. I have gone through the code in debugging mode and when p1 becomes 0, it jumps out of the for loop and I don't understand why, because it should go through the loop one more time and then decrement to -1 and exit the loop.

> Given an integer array nums, move all 0's to the end of it while maintaining the relative order of the non-zero elements.
> Note that you must do this in-place without making a copy of the array.
>
> Example 1:
>
> **Input**: nums = [0,1,0,3,12]                **Output**: [1,3,12,0,0]
>
> Example 2:
>
> **Input**: nums = [0]    **Output**: [0]

````
package random.leetCode;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class MoveZeroes_TwoPointers_283 {
    public void moveZeroes(int[] nums) {
        int p2 = 0;
        int tempIndex = 0;
        int lastIndex = nums.length - 1;

        for (int p1 = nums.length - 1; p1>=0;  p1--)
        {
            if (nums[p1] == 0)
            {
                if (p1 == nums.length - 1 && nums.length == 1)
                {
                    break;
                }

                tempIndex = p1;
                p2 = p1 + 1;
                while (p2 <= lastIndex)
                {
                    int temp = nums[p1];
                    nums[p1] = nums[p2];
                    nums[p2] = temp;
                    p2 += 1;
                    p1 += 1;
                }
                p1 = tempIndex -1;
                lastIndex--;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MoveZeroes_TwoPointers_283 example = new MoveZeroes_TwoPointers_283();
//       int[] numbersToBeSorted = new int[]{0,1,0,3,12,0,11,0,0};
//        int[] numbersToBeSorted = new int[]{0};
//        int[] numbersToBeSorted = new int[]{0,0};
//        int[] numbersToBeSorted = new int[]{1};
//        int[] numbersToBeSorted = new int[]{1,1};
       int[] numbersToBeSorted = new int[]{0,0,1};
        example.moveZeroes(numbersToBeSorted);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbersToBeSorted));
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int p1 = nums.length - 1; p1>=0;  p1--) {
...
    tempIndex = p1;
...
    p1 = tempIndex -1;
}
```

You are decrementing p1 twice in this loop. You probably did not mean to.

Comment: The purpose of that decrement is to return p1 to the position previous of the last found 0 so it can restart the search for the next 0 backwards. Eliminating the decrement at this point actually returns the same array for the case [1,0,0]

Comment: @Art If I change it to `p1 = tempIndex;` (without the -1) I get [1,0,0], which is the expected result. If you see some inputs where the code misbehaves, maybe there are more problems.

Comment: You are right! I was mixing things up and misinterpreting the correct result as incorrect. Indeed, with your suggestion the algorithm passed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I think the problem is when you find two consecutive zeros and managing these pointers. Let me know what you think about this algorithm.

```java
void main() {
    int[] input = new int[]{0,0,1};
    
    // whenever finds a zero, move it to the end
    for (int i=0; i < input.length; i++) {
       if (input[i] == 0) moveToEnd(i, input);
    }

    System.out.println(input);
}

// move to the end by swapping elements
void moveToEnd(pos, arr) {
   for (int i = pos + 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
       int aux = arr[pos];
       arr[pos] = arr[i];
       arr[i] = aux;
       post = i;
   }
}
```

Comment: I updated it to fit the leetcode requirement

```public void moveZeroes(int[] nums) {
            
    // whenever finds a zero, move it to the end
    for (int i=0; i < nums.length; i++) {
       if (nums[i] == 0) moveToEnd(i, nums);
    }

   // System.out.println(input);
}

// move to the end by swapping elements
void moveToEnd(int pos, int[] arr) {
   for (int i=pos; i < arr.length; i++) {
       int aux = arr[pos];
       arr[pos] = arr[i];
       arr[i] = aux;
   }
    }```

and it fails at this testcase:
[0,1,0,3,12] - ouput = [12,3,0,1,0]

Comment: it's the best i could do editing, sorry !

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I haven' properly tested it but the idea is there, I think I might have a bug in the moveToEnd method, but the logic I think it works. What do you think @Art ? 
Update: I fixed the loop, I forgot to keep pos updated!

Comment: i have moved past this question, but you can check here: https://leetcode.com/problems/move-zeroes/ - it has tens of test cases and it will show you the speed and memory